# If I cat file to other file is there way to get them separate again?

Tags: command-line, cat

If I use `cat pic1.png >> pic2.png` is there way to get the `pic1.png` out of that `pic2.png`?

I know it works if I simply use some archive file and just simply unarchive it but I want to know is it possible other way.

Answer (score 3):

With `cat file_b >> file_a` you are just appending the content of `file_b` to `file_a`. No format change, no other manipulation (1)(2).

You can go back by just removing the last bytes of the files; probably something like

```
 head --bytes=-$(wc --bytes file_b | cut -d" " -f1) file_a > old_file_a
```

should work.

Explanation:

```
wc --bytes file_b
```

returns the length of `file_b` in bytes (and the name of the files, like "`5678 file_b`")

```
wc --bytes file_b | cut -d" " -f1
```

gets rid of the file name in the output of `wc` by keeping just the first field ("`5678`"). Then we use a process substitution to put that number as an argument to `head`:

```
head --bytes=-5678 file_a
```

outputs all the contents of `file_a` *but* the last 5678 bytes.

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) In the OP example, I doubt that the `pic2.png` file is still a valid PNG file...

(2) Included in "other manipulation" is the fact that there is no recording of the original length of the file or any marker that separate the two files. If after the `cat` you delete `file_b` you have no way to separate them again without knowing the length of the original files. An archiver format (tar, zip, rar) is doing exactly this bookkeeping for you (and compress and checksum and other thing, sometime).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at the PNG file format

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

The PNG file format has a header and a series of chunks that define the way a PNG file is constructed. If you chain through the chunks you should be able to extract the PNG files. You might get lucky and just use the first 8 bytes of the PNG file as an identifier to find the separation point.